# Kubernetes AKS bind domain

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

Question regarding AKS, each time release CD. The Kubernetes will give random IP Address to my services. 
I would like to know how to bind the domain to the IP?

Can someone give me some link or article to read?

Answer (score 4):

You have two options.

You can either deploy a Service with `type=LoadBalancer` which will provision a cloud load balancer. You can then point your DNS entry to that provisioned LoadBalancer with (for example) a CNAME.

More information on this can be found [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/create-external-load-balancer/)

Your second option is to use an [Ingress Controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#ingress-controllers) with an [Ingress Resource](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/). This offers much finer grained access via url parameters. You'll probably need to deploy your ingress controller pod/service with a service `Type=LoadBalancer` though, to make it externally accessible.

[Here's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress) an article which explains how to do ingress on Azure with the [nginx-ingress-controller](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx)